# Django model field validators: coding style

Tags: django

Could you have a look at the code example below:

```
from datetime import date
from rest_framework import serializers 

def validate_age(date_of_birth):
    today = date.today()
    age = today.year - date_of_birth.year - ((today.month, today.day) < (date_of_birth.month, date_of_birth.day))
    if (not(20 < age < 30)):
        raise serializers.ValidationError("You are no eligible for the job")
    return dob

class EligibilitySerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    email = serializers.EmailField()
    name = serializers.CharField(max_length=200)
    date_of_birth = serializers.DateField(validators=[validate_age])
```

Suppose, this validate_age will not be used anywhere else. In this case a reasonable choice would be to incapsulate it inside the class as a private method.

Is it possible in django somehow? If it is not possible, maybe a notation should be used? Something like this: _validate_age(date_of_birth). So that programmers should know that this function definitely is not for reusing, not for importing.